# Listar somente se a outra tabela não tiver uma demissão

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde. Preciso fazer uma listagem de funcionários por ano. Por exemplo. Funcionários ativos de 2018, porém estou tendo problemas, pois em 2019 alguns foram demitidos ai não lista os mesmos, sendo que uso a tabela Funcionários e a ExamesFuncionarios.

**Editado:** Seguinte, usei a verificação para saber se tinha exames demissionais, até ai tudo bem, não lista essa pessoa, porém essa mesma pessoa tem no memso ano o exame de retorno ao trabalho, ou até mesmo outro exame e eu não quero e não posso que ele exiba. Como faço a condição para que se caso haja exame demissional para tal pessoa ela pule a pessoa mesmo que tenha outros exames.

Seguem os Códigos e as tabelas.

Tabela Funcionário ->

```
 CREATE TABLE `funcionario` (
  `CodFuncionario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `funcionario_CodEmpresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `funcionario_CodSetor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_CodCBO` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_Nome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_DataNac` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_DataAdm` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_Sexo` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_CTPS` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_RG` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_NIT` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_Ativo` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_Cpf` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_DataDemissao` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_TrabalhoAltura` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_TrabalhoConfinado` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_HoraEntrada` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_HoraSaida` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_InicioRepouso` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_FimRepouso` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_Epi` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_RiscoFisico` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_RiscoQuimico` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_RiscoBiologico` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_RiscoErgonomico` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_HoraEntrada_S` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_HoraSaida_S` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_InicioRepouso_S` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_FimRepouso_S` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funcionario_ExameOcupacional` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodFuncionario`) USING BTREE
)
```

Tebela ExamesFuncionarios ->

```
CREATE TABLE `examefuncionario` (
  `idExameFunc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `exameFunc_CodFuncionario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exameFunc_NrSeq` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exameFunc_CodExame` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_Data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_Tipo` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_Natureza` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_Apto` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_DataProximo` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_Resultado` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_FlgRefSeq` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exameFunc_DataUltimo` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idExameFunc`) USING BTREE
)
```

Códigos Mysql 1ª forma ->

```
select funcionario.CodFuncionario,funcionario.funcionario_Nome
from funcionario
join examefuncionario on examefuncionario.exameFunc_CodFuncionario = funcionario.CodFuncionario and date_format(examefuncionario.exameFunc_Data, "%Y") = '2018'
where funcionario_CodEmpresa = 179 
and date_format(funcionario_DataAdm, "%Y") <= '2018'
group by funcionario.CodFuncionario
order by funcionario.funcionario_Nome ASC
```

Códigos Mysql 2ª forma ->

```
select funcionario.CodFuncionario,funcionario.funcionario_Nome
from funcionario
join examefuncionario on examefuncionario.exameFunc_CodFuncionario = funcionario.CodFuncionario and date_format(examefuncionario.exameFunc_Data, "%Y") = '2018'
where funcionario_CodEmpresa = 179 
and date_format(funcionario_DataAdm, "%Y") <= '2018'
and funcionario_Ativo = 'S' 
group by funcionario.CodFuncionario
order by funcionario.funcionario_Nome ASC
```

Código editado:

```
select *
from funcionario

join examefuncionario 
    on examefuncionario.exameFunc_CodFuncionario = funcionario.CodFuncionario 
    and date_format(examefuncionario.exameFunc_Data, "%Y") = '2018'
    and examefuncionario.exameFunc_Natureza != 'D'

where funcionario_CodEmpresa = 179 
and date_format(funcionario_DataAdm, "%Y") <= '2018'

group by funcionario.CodFuncionario
order by funcionario.funcionario_Nome ASC
```

Preciso que liste os funcionários que em 2018 não tiveram exames demissionais.
Em 2018 o funcionário estava ativo porem em 2019 está inativo, então quando uso o where do mesmo alguns que em 2018 estavam ativos não lista.

Comment: Não basta você listar os que estão com funcionario_DataDemissao NULL (não demitidos) ou o ano de funcionario_DataDemissao seja maior ou igual a 2018 (estiveram ativos pelo menos em algum momento de 2018)?

Comment: Da maneira como está seu critério de junção você só selecionará na junção os funcionários que fizeram pelo menos um exame em 2018. Não me parece estar de acordo com o texto de sua pergunta.

Comment: Como sua tabela examefuncionario possui o campo exameFunc_Data não é necessário também verificar se o ano de tal data é 2018 e o tipo de exame é o que deseja?

Comment: Preciso verificar, pois esse relatório é anual, ou seja, no ano de 2019 tudo muda.

Comment: Mas os códigos que você postou não fazem tal verificação.

Comment: date_format(examefuncionario.exameFunc_Data, "%Y") = '2018' so exibe os exames referente a 2018. Porém tem alguns funcionarios que fazer dois, um deles é demissional e eu não posso listar ele, e também não posso usar o funcionario_Ativo = 'S'  porque dai não vai listar outros que em 2018 estava ativos mas agora em 2019 estão inativos.

Comment: Qual a sua versão do `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o `NOT EXISTS` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT f.CodFuncionario,
       f.funcionario_Nome
  FROM funcionario f
 WHERE f.funcionario_CodEmpresa = 179
   AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM examefuncionario ef
               WHERE ef.exameFunc_CodFuncionario = f.CodFuncionario
                 AND DATE_FORMAT(ef.exameFunc_Data, "%Y") = '2018'
                 AND ef.exameFunc_Natureza <> 'D')
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM examefuncionario ef
                   WHERE ef.exameFunc_CodFuncionario = f.CodFuncionario
                     AND DATE_FORMAT(ef.exameFunc_Data, "%Y") = '2018'
                     AND ef.exameFunc_Natureza = 'D')
 GROUP BY f.CodFuncionario
 ORDER BY f.funcionario_Nome ASC
```

Comment: Blz, vou tentar. Obrigado.

Comment: A questão é que eu não posso usar a condição se ele está ou não ativo, pois isso seria deste instante, e eu preciso que liste no caso do ano passado, onde p funcionário estava admitido, porém este ano ele está demitido.

Comment: @JoséLuis entendi, vou editar a resposta

Comment: Se eu resolver isso fico grato a todos, porque isso ta me dando um trabalho e não posso fazer meus outros sistemas.

Comment: @JoséLuis pronto, adicionei na resposta. Só que isso não compreende pessoas que foram recontratadas, não sei se é o caso

Comment: Cara ta quase certo, porém falta algo. O certo deveria listar 48 e está listando 44

Comment: A condição tem que ignorar qualquer um que tenha demissional, mesmo que o mesmo funcionário tenha dois exames.

Comment: @JoséLuis mas é isso que está fazendo. Veja se você não consegue bolar um exemplo no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) senão fica difícil te ajudar

Comment: Pior que que tem mais de 810 registros no total. Dai fica difícil de separar.

Comment: Me mande seu contato por email. E se tu poder me ajudar por acesso remoto. joseluis.ald@hotmail.com

Comment: O que eu preciso a modo grosso seria assim -> se funcionario tal tiver uma demissão não listar.

Comment: @JoséLuis então, o problema é que essa `query` já faz isso. Aparentemente você tem alguma particularidade nas suas tabelas que impede o resultado ser favorável. Só podemos corrigir se você bolar um exemplo executável. Para isso você não precisa de todos os dados, só dos que são necessários para elaboração da resposta, de preferência em um fiddle executável, assim você pode demonstrar o problema e podemos propor uma solução

Comment: Tu não tem como me ajudar remotamente? Assim poderia lhe explicar melhor também. Este é o ultimo processo que preciso pra entregar este sistema, e o cliente está nos meus ouvidos se é que você me entende.

Comment: Boa noite, não consegui usar o DB Fiddle nem um outro, então resolvi upar no Mega. https://mega.nz/#!tY0n1SLY!oIOgvNDWLRGWikDbIztzQv8Lg9TxpOFMIQBxBMDtNR0

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95399/discussion-between-sorack-and-jose-luis).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você tenha que colocar também condiçoes relacionadas ao tipo ou natureza de exame. Olhando apenas as amostras das tabelas que vocë passou, eu fico um pouco na duvida do que seria:

```
exameFunc_Tipo     varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
exameFunc_Natureza varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Talvez resolva o seu problema se vocë colocar uma condicao do tipo NOT IN  para pegar os funcionarios que nao tiveram exames do tipo/natureza demissional no ano de 2018, entende?

Existe uma outra questao tbm... ao fazer o join com a Tabela ExamesFuncionarios, você ja leva em considereçao que todo funcionario ativo em 2018 fez algum tipo de exame. Você tem que avaliar se essa condiçao é verdadeira. Todos os anos todos os funcionarios da empresa passam por algum tipo de exame todos os anos? Porque se nao passam, imagino que nao vai existir registro na tabela exames funcionarios... se nao existe registro, quando voc faz o join, esses funcionarios que nao fizeram nenhum exame em 2018 estarao automaticamente fora do resultado da consulta.

Comment: Isso, isso é um relatória anual de tudo que ocorre dentro da empresa. Natureza seria 'Demissional, Periódico e tal'. Como uso o not in?